# How can I negate a field value in MongoDB Spring Data while performing aggregation?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data

I have this condition and I would like the else part to return a negative value of the field. How can I perform the negation on the result of ConvertOperators.valueOf(ConditionalOperators.ifNull("cost").then(0)).convertToDouble() since I am using the condition in the project stage.

```
    Cond cond1 = ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("status").is("inactive"))
                    .thenValueOf("cost")
.otherwise(ConvertOperators.valueOf(ConditionalOperators.ifNull("cost").then(0)).convertToDouble());

    AggregationOperation project = Aggregation.project()
            .and(cond1).as("cost")
            .and("timeStamp").as("timeStamp")
            .and("name").as("name")
            .and("status").as("status");
```

Comment: You multiply a number with `-1` to get its negative value; and you would use a multiply aggregate operator.

Comment: Which multiply aggregate operator can i use here? 
I tried ArithmetricOperators.Mutiply.valueOf(value) but it accepts one parameter

Comment: `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ArithmeticOperators.Multiply` has two methods: the static `valueOf()` and instance `multiplyBy()`. Use them together. The first method gets the field reference and the second gets the `-1` as parameter.

Comment: Thank you @Prasad

This worked for me in the else part.

    .otherwise(new ArithmeticOperatorFactory(ConvertOperators.valueOf(ConditionalOperators.ifNull("loanAmount").then(0)).convertToDouble()).multiplyBy(-1));